# Hi. I faced a problem while excuting my code. But I get an error 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str' for the last pointer

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

```
 lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'i', 'u', 'y', 'l', 'i']

 if(len(lst)%3==0):
     pointer = 0
     for i in lst:
         for j in range(pointer, pointer+3):
             print(lst[j])
             pointer += 1
 else:
    rem = 3
    pointer = 0
    for i in lst:
        for j in range(pointer, pointer+3):
            print(lst[j])
            pointer += 1
            rem -= 1
            if (pointer > rem):
                pointer = lst [0]
            print(lst[j])
```

I am not sure if I have a good approach or not, but I wanted my pointer to get to the first element of the list, if the number of elements is not divisible by 3.

Comment: The error occurs because you are setting the pointer to the character from the list: `pointer = lst [0]` which is changing `pointer` to a string value rather than an int.

Answer (score 3):

When you say

```
pointer = lst[0]
```

the pointer variable will now be storing a string (`lst[0]` should be the string `'a'` from your list). So when your code later runs into the line:

```
pointer += 1
```

you are now attempting to add the string `'a'` to the integer `1`. That's where the type error comes from. You can either "add" two numbers, or "concatenate" two strings. You can't combine a string and an integer without explicitly converting one into the other.